# How can To override CSS Class with another in different css file

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC Project and I need to use 2 CSS stylesheets
One I will loaded in the shared layout and the other in a view in the project

the problem is the two files have some similar class names, and the classes in  the layout stylesheet always overrides the classes in the View stylesheet,

I want the classes in view stylesheet to override the other(layout) in specific area of that view

**Code:**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Dropdown Menu</h1>
    <ul>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">First Menu <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Second Menu <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Third Menu <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I just need to force this area to read styles from `style.css` not from any other stylesheet.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: add your css part in minimized format

Comment: Is it a particular class in style.css or the entire style.css

Comment: Just add `!important` after each css rule (like `.dropdown { color: blue !important; } `) in your view css file. It will override your layout CSS.

Comment: Please, for the love of anyone who has to maintain your code in the future, do **not** use `!important`. Instead, learn about specificity in CSS.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks buddy. Actually I was unaware of that *specificity in CSS*.